# How to fix backend date always showing 2020?

Tags: magento2, backend, date, special-price

I've looked far and wide for an answer to this problem and could not find one.
Perhaps you can help.

**The Problem:**
In the Magento Admin Backend Panel, I am trying to set the Special Price Date so that the original price shows along with the discounted price (on the catalog page). My problem is that regardless of the date I input, it always changes the year to 2020. I've tried selecting the date in calendar, I've tried typing it out. Always the same result.

**Where am I making these changes:**
Admin Panel :: Product/Catalog/ edit -> advanced pricing

**Additional Note:**
I checked if this happens with other date selections and had the same exact problem with the "Set Product as New From" field. The date all stays fine except for the year which keeps defaulting to 2020 no matter which year I input.

Comment: Please check ur Server Timezone first as well as Magento set Locale

Comment: Checked it. Time seems fine. On messages and orders received, the time appears correctly.

Comment: hi! did you solved the problem? i have the same problem too!